# Invalid TCP segment

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, tcp, sequence, tcpclient

Clients generate SSL packets using the code below
However, before long, the client suddenly sends the GET to the wrong sequence number
I don't know why, and what should I check ??

Plesae check it out

```
import ssl, socket, time

server = "192.168.1.1"
port =  443
conn = "yes"
interval = 0.001
version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2


if version == "tls1":
    TLSv = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
elif version == "tls1.1":
    TLSv = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_1
else:
    TLSv = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2


try:
    if conn == "no":
        try:
            while True:
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect((server, port))
                request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\n\r\n" % server
                s = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile=None, certfile=None, server_side=False, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, \
                                    ssl_version=TLSv)
                print('SSL Start = =(VIP: {0}, Interval: {1},  Version: {2})'.format(server, interval, version))
                s.send(request.encode())
                time.sleep(interval)
                s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR) 

        except:
            print("Failed")
    else:
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((server, port))
            request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\n\r\n" % server
            s = ssl.wrap_socket(s, keyfile=None, certfile=None, server_side=False, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE, \
                                ssl_version=TLSv)
            while True:
                print('SSL Start = (VIP: {0}, Interval: {1}, Version: {2})'.format(server, interval, version))
                s.send(request.encode())
                time.sleep(interval)
        except:
            print("Failed")
finally:
    print("execution")
```

Comment: *"the client suddenly sends the GET to the wrong sequence number "* - it is unclear to me what you mean with this. From the perspective of the application sequence numbers are irrelevant and the user space program has no influence of which sequence numbers are used at all within a TCP socket. But your code looks broken to me in that the client only sends requests and never reads a response.

Comment: You aren’t closing your sockets. Fix and retest.

Comment: I see why
Transmit TCP Zero Window after a certain period of time after the code is executed
Is there a solution